# Gem:File Permission Error Issue with gems (not duplicate)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, rbenv

I have been trying to install jekyll and bundler, and I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I have tried so many things suggested by other posts. Ran rbenv, appended eval "$(rbenv init -)" to my bash_profile in order to run it automatically, did some stuff with sudo, and also tried installing using:

```
gem install jekyll --user-install
```

but then when I try to make a jekyll command the return is:

```
-bash: jekyll: no command found
```

I am at a loss. I know basically nothing about Unix and have been trying this for hours. Any thoughts?

P.S. Please do not mark as duplicate because other posts have not answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't add the user gem bin dir to the `PATH`.

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'
```

this will show the gem user dir.

then add `OUTPUT_FROM_LAST_CMD/bin` to your path, or simply add

```
export PATH="$(ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin":$PATH
```

to your `~/.bashrc`

---

1. http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install